# How to find a server's machinekey if it wasn't set

Tags: asp.net, web-config, machinekey

Trying to transfer servers but a connection string is encrypted and there is no machinekey set in the web.config.  Is there anyway to find out what the machinekey was on the old server so we can set it on the new server?

Answer (score 1):

Why not just decrypt using the -pd switch on the original server? - for example:

```
aspnet_regiis.exe -pdf "connectionStrings" "C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\MySite"
```